# Find an existing messaging group when given the potential members

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an application where users can create messaging groups. MessageGroups have members through MessageMemberships. MessageMemberships belongs to a 'profile', which is polymorphic due to their being different types of 'profiles' in the db.

MessageGroup

```rb
class MessageGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :coach_profiles, through: :message_memberships, source: :profile, source_type: "CoachProfile"
  has_many :parent_profiles, through: :message_memberships, source: :profile, source_type: "ParentProfile"
  has_many :customers, through: :message_memberships, source: :profile, source_type: "Customer"
end
```

MessageMembership

```rb
class MessageMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message_group
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my UI, I'd like to be able to first query to see if a messaging group exists with exactly x members so I can use that, rather than creating an entirely new messaging group (similar to how Slack or iMessages will find you an existing thread).

How would you go about querying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code (not tested) below assumes:

- You have (or can add) a `message_memberships_count` `counter_cache` column to the `message_groups` table. (and maybe adding an index to the `message_memberships_count` column to speed up the query)
- You have proper unique indexing in the `message_memberships` table that will prevent a profile from being added to the same `message_group` multiple times

How it works:

- There is a loop that will do multiple `inner joins` on the same table to ensure that the association exists for each profile
- The query will then check that the total number of members in the group is equal to the number of profiles

```
class MessageGroup < ApplicationRecord
 ...
 def self.for_profiles(profiles)
    query = "SELECT \"message_groups\".* FROM \"message_groups\""

    profiles.each do |profile|
      klass = profile.class.name
      # provide an alias to the table to prevent `PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR
      table_alias = "message_memberships_#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{klass}_#{profile.id}")[0..6]}"
      query += " INNER JOIN \"message_memberships\" \"#{table_alias}\" ON \"#{table_alias}\".\"message_group_id\" = \"message_groups\".\"id\" AND \"#{table_alias}\".\"profile_type\" = #{klass} AND \"#{table_alias}\".\"profile_id\" = #{profile.id}"
    end
    
    query += " where \"message_groups\".\"message_memberships_count\" = #{profiles.length}"

    self.find_by_sql(query)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this should work. Going to play with it tomorrow and will circle back to accept this. The counter cache solves a lot of the problems I was getting hung up on!

Comment: Thanks AbM, I now have a working solution for this based on the above answer. I'm going to post my tested solution below for reference, but accepting yours since you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AbM's answer I arrived at the following. This has the same assumptions as the previous answer, counter cache and unique indexing should be in place.

```
  def self.find_direct_with_profiles!(profiles)
    # Not present, some authorization checks that may raise (hence the bang method name)
 
    # Loop through the profiles and join them all together so we get a join that contains
    # all the data we need in order to filter it down
    join = ""
    conditions = ""
    profiles.each_with_index do |profile, index|
      klass = profile.class.name
      # provide an alias to the table to prevent `PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR
      table_alias = "message_memberships_#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{klass}_#{profile.id}")[0..6]}"
      join += " INNER JOIN \"message_memberships\" \"#{table_alias}\" ON \"#{table_alias}\".\"message_group_id\" = \"message_groups\".\"id\""
      condition_join = index == 0 ? 'where' : ' and'
      conditions += "#{condition_join} \"#{table_alias}\".\"profile_type\" = '#{klass}' and \"#{table_alias}\".\"profile_id\" = #{profile.id}"
    end

    # Add one
    size_conditional = " and \"message_groups\".\"message_memberships_count\" = #{profiles.size}"
    # Add any other conditions you may need
    conditions += "#{size_conditional}"
    query = "SELECT \"message_groups\".* FROM \"message_groups\" #{join} #{conditions}"

    # find_by_sql returns an array with hydrated models from the select statement. In this case I am just grabbing the first one to match other finder active record method conventions
    self.find_by_sql(query).first
  end
```